# How to tell if an add on is present. Using Python

Tags: scripting

I want to add a button to a script that will detect if an add-on is present and then enable additional options if it is. I'm not sure how to go about locating this in python itself. But I think this would work better than having options that boot into an error if the add-on isn't present.

for example:
if addon_prefs.automirror:

Wouldn't I need to be more specific to query the add ons folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import addon_utils

addon_name = 'some_addon'

success = addon_utils.enable('some_addon')
if success:
    print("enabled", success.bl_info['name'])
else:
    print(addon_name, "is not found")
```

`addon_utils.enable` returns None if it failed to enable the addon, but returns a module reference (which evaluates to True) if it did manage to enable it.

---

The precise name of the addon is either:

- the .py name if it's a single python file addon,
- the directory name if it's directory based

Sometimes, especially prevalent with github `.zips`, the addon name is suffixed with `-master`. The addon name would then be 'some_addon-master'.

---

**over the top, addon seeking**

`bpy.utils.script_paths()` returns a list of directories where Blender looks for add-ons. With a bit of python-fu you can iterate through them and find any *.py* or *sub-directories* that contain part of an add-on name -- Then try to enable it :)

Comment: thats interesting. Im also curious in how one finds that particular information? How would I get the precise name of the add on Im looking for? The py? Or just the add on name?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is:

```
import addon_utils

addon_utils.check("addon_name.py")
```

this just checks the module state and does not enable it. Returns a tuple `(loaded_default, loaded_state)`. If the addon is enabled and is not enabled by default it will result in (False, True).

Comment: so what about if the add on is in a folder and the name of the file shown in preferences is _init_.py wouldnt I have to change that then?

Comment: @masterxeon1001 yes you would have to change it and use the addon folder name instead.